# Voltage spikes in DC motors during switching

Tags: dc-motor

When commutation occurs in a DC motor with multiple windings, why isn't there a voltage spike across the disconnected windings? How is the inductance of the winding addressed?

Comment: There is an inductive kick. Easily demonstrated in brushless DC motors where the brushes have been replaced by electronics and measures must be taken to handle the voltage spikes. If I remember right, that's why in brushed motors, brush resistance and/or the fact the brushes might overlap windings a bit is desirable. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/296118/how-does-armature-reaction-affect-brushes-in-dc-generators/296121#296121 There is another question like this on here that is answered. I'll try to find it.

Answer (score 4):

The windings are not actually disconnected. The commutator segments are connected to points along a continuous winding. In moving from one segment to the next, the brushes essentially move sections of the armature winding from one current path to a parallel current path. With each transition, the current is reversed in only a section of the armature. There are voltage spikes and some arcing, but it is not as dramatic as it would be for opening an inductive circuit.